# Is it necessary to read Aristotle's books in order to understand St. Thomas Aquinas's «Summa Theologica»?

Tags: philosophy, thomas-aquinas, summa-theologica

Is it necessary to read Aristotle's books in order to understand St. Thomas Aquinas's [*Summa Theologica*](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/index.html)?

Comment: Necessary for whom, or for what purpose? And which books?

Comment: @MattGutting I don't think a question can be any more clear than that.

Comment: @mil: Matt has asked a reasonable question. The fact that your question has received 3 downvotes, and 4 close votes should serve as an indicator that your question has some serious problems. As a newcomer here, you might do well to heed the advice of those who have been here for a while, rather than taking an argumentative stance.

Answer (score 4):

Although St. Thomas Aquinas is said to have "reconciled" Aristotle with Christian theology, he rejects much of Aristotle (e.g., [he rejects that Aristotle thought the world is eternal](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeEternitateMundi.htm)).
<sup>(Interestingly, St. Thomas refers to Aristotle as "Aristotle" when he disagrees with him and as "The Philosopher" when he agrees with him.)</sup>

#### Understand Scholastic terminology.

St. Thomas can be understood without reading any Aristotle; however, it is necessary to understand the Scholastic terminology he uses. To aid with this, see:

- [this list of scholastic terms](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/catholicteaching/philosophy/definitions.htm) (cf. [this list of scholastic axioms](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/catholicteaching/philosophy/axiomata.htm))
- Roy J. DeFerrari's [*A Lexicon of St. Thomas Aquinas*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/2847) (1948)

#### Understand the doctrine of actuality and potentiality.

Philosophically, hylemorphism (the doctrine of actuality and potentiality) forms the basis of Thomism. See:

- St. Thomas's *opusculum* ("short work") [*On the Principles of Natures* (*De Principii Naturæ*)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DePrincNaturae.htm)

  - <sup>This was written at the request of Br. Sylvester, who wanted St. Thomas to summarize the natural philosophy that undergirds his works so students wouldn't have to spend too much time reading Aristotle [*Physics*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Physics.htm), which St. Thomas also commentated.</sup>
- [Fr. Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Garrigou-Lagrange)'s short work [*The Essence & Topicality of Thomism*](https://www.lulu.com/shop/r%C3%A9ginald-garrigou-lagrange-op/the-essence-topicality-of-thomism/hardcover/product-21419402.html) ([e-book](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4540)) and the longer [*Reality: A Synthesis of Thomistic Thought*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8906888-reality) ([free online ed.](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3033)), esp. "[Chapter 5: Act And Potency](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3033)"

  - <sup>cf. [my review / summary](https://www.worldcat.org/profiles/Geremia10/reviews/963892?reviewaction=fetchfull) of *Reality*</sup>
- [The 24 Thomistic Theses](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm)

#### Reading Aristotle not necessary but could be helpful

If you want to read Aristotle (it certainly doesn't hurt in helping one understand St. Thomas), read the following works by Aristotle alongside St. Thomas's commentaries on them:

- logical work: [*Posterior Analytics* with St. Thomas's commentary](https://isidore.co/aquinas/PostAnalytica.htm)

  - <sup>cf. [this commentary on St. Thomas's commentary](http://www.pvspade.com/Logic/docs/Weisheipl.pdf) ☺</sup>
- natural philosophy work: [*Physics* with St. Thomas's commentary](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Physics.htm)

  - <sup>The last book of this influenced [St. Thomas's *quinque viæ* proofs of God's existence](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP002.html#FPQ2A3THEP1).</sup>